# Extract Parameter constraints from Natural Language text

Tags: nlp

I am working on a project where I want to parse and verify CLI commands based on a documentation. The documentation provides a structured list of parameters for the commands, that I was easily able to extract. However, I am also interested in each parameter's data types and constraints.

Unfortunately, these are only described by short description strings. They might be something like

- "The value is an integer."
- "The value is a number from 1 to 10."
- "It is either '1', '2', or '3'."
- "A string (spaces supported)".

I would like to find a way to automatically evaluate or at least simplify these descriptions, so that I can use them for the verification procedure. However, since they really don't follow any common pattern, rule-based matching approaches I have tried until now didn't provide reliable results, and as I am still relatively new with NLP, I don't know what other tools could be used to tackle such a problem.

Is there any sort of commonly used approach that may be helpful for me to extract all constraints from these parameter descriptions?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Is there a predefined format that the verification procedure expects? There is a need to define a formal format to represent all the possible constraints anyway, and the design could be similar to a translation problem from an input string to this target format.

Comment: As the documentation was written for human readers, many of these constraints are actually quite complex. They range from "Integer between 1 and 100", to "ID in the form XX-XX-XXX" and everything in-between. In a perfect world, I would like to have a way to extract even the constraints themselves as a first step and then think of how to implement them for verification in a second step.
If that's not  reasonable, I might also be able to generalize it, and maybe drop the more complex constraints so that I can come up with a formal list of constraints first.

Comment: I think that you should design the complete system from the start, because the problem is not fully specified without the format in the middle: constraint as free  string -> constraint in predefined format -> automatic verification. The format needs to be able to represent all the possible constraints, but it needs to be as simplified as possible in order to make the automatic treatment possible. So it's probably a crucial part to design, and it's not necessarily easy.